# Gradle failed to import aar/jar files Android

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I created an Android project and now I want to move that project in Android studio, I successfully done that on Mac machine and working fine but when I try to execute same gradle / android studio script on Windows machine it's failing getting following exception

```
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not expand ZIP 'C:\CodeBase\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\CheckoutAnd4.0\jars\classes.jar'.
```

I tried to add Jar file then also getting same exception.
Gradle Script

For Jar `compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')`
For Aar `compile(name: 'CheckoutAnd4.0', ext: 'aar')`

So I want to know whether there is anything missing with Gradle script or Android project

More info -

My jar containing Aux/com class, And widows don't allows that to compile/create in build folder.

Comment: close android studio, go to yours project folder, delete both `build` and `app/build` folders. Then run AS. It should work

Comment: Hi All,I got the answer the issue with jar file only its containing the windows banned files which throwing exception.

Comment: Hi @NitinGaikwad, did you find a way around this? I have a Jar file included in one of my projects which uses Proguard and has at least 2 classes popping this error: _aux.class_ and _con.class_